# Laravel Cron Job not working on AWS lightsail LAMP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, cron, lamp

**I am using Laravel 7 and AWS lightsail LAMP server for my application.**

When I am running this

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

command manually it's working properly. But, when I am creating a cron job for this it's not working.

Here is my cron code as [laravel documention](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling):

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is my `app/Console/Karnel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\DeactiveCoupon::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('coupon:deactive')->everyMinute();
         $schedule->command('queue:restart')->everyMinute();
         $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

**But, if I add this cron:**

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && touch mytestfile.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

It's creating a new file named mytestfile.txt

**But, this Laravel command not working in cron!**

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Try using the full path to the `php` binary e.g. `/usr/bin/php` or wherever it is. cron tasks might not define a PATH variable

Comment: However, adding a log output to your cron config will be very helpful to get information on what is going wrong.

Comment: please tell me more details @apokryfos

Comment: Can you please tell me more details? @DharmaSaputra

Comment: Run `which php` and whatever result you get (probably `/usr/bin/php` or something like that) use that for your cron command definition e.g.  `* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Try change the output to a file to a file instead of `/dev/null`  for example: `* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && php artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/laravel-schedule.log 2>&1`. With this config you can see if any errors in the `/var/log/laravel-schedule.log` file

Comment: after I run `which php`  I got `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php` and my cron code is: `* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` **It's working for me** Thanks @apokryfos bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I run

`which php`
I got
`/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`

and my cron code is:

`* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

**It's working for me**
Thanks @apokryfos bro

Answer (score 0):

Yes on live server you can register it through cron job
[image]

then you can register you command in cron job. you can ask you server provider for this command and then register like this
[image]

command look like this
/usr/local/bin/php /home/escuelar/your folder name/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I am using AWS lightsail LAMP. I have no Cpanel here.

Comment: then you can ask your service provider they can help you

Comment: i also take help form service team when i face this task first time